# Rmarkdown: how to show partial output from chunk?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have an Rmarkdown document and I would like to show only partial output from a code chunk.

For example, consider the following:

````
```{r echo=1:2, eval=-2, collapse=TRUE}
mod <- lm(speed ~ dist, data = cars)
summary(mod)
out <- capture.output(summary(mod))
cat(c("[...]", out[9:12], "[...]"), sep = "\n")
```
````

which produces

```
mod <- lm(speed ~ dist, data = cars)
## summary(mod)
## [...]
## Coefficients:
##             Estimate Std. Error t value         Pr(>|t|)    
## (Intercept)  8.28391    0.87438   9.474 0.00000000000144 ***
## dist         0.16557    0.01749   9.464 0.00000000000149 ***
## [...]
```

but what I would like to obtain is

```
mod <- lm(speed ~ dist, data = cars)
summary(mod)
## [...]
## Coefficients:
##             Estimate Std. Error t value         Pr(>|t|)    
## (Intercept)  8.28391    0.87438   9.474 0.00000000000144 ***
## dist         0.16557    0.01749   9.464 0.00000000000149 ***
## [...]
```

See the different format of `summary(mod)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution for my problem

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
# the default output hook
hook_output <- knit_hooks$get('output')
knit_hooks$set(output = function(x, options) {
  if (!is.null(n <- options$out.lines)) {
    n <- as.numeric(n)
    x <- unlist(stringr::str_split(x, "\n"))
    nx <- length(x) 
    x <- x[pmin(n,nx)]
    if(min(n) > 1)  
      x <- c(paste(options$comment, "[...]"), x)
    if(max(n) < nx) 
      x <- c(x, paste(options$comment, "[...]"))
    x <- paste(c(x, "\n"), collapse = "\n")
  }
  hook_output(x, options)
    })
```

```{r collapse=TRUE, out.lines = 9:12}
mod <- lm(speed ~ dist, data = cars)
summary(mod)
```

```{r collapse=TRUE, out.lines = 1:3}
summary(mod)
```

```{r collapse=TRUE, out.lines = 17:18}
summary(mod)
```

```{r collapse=TRUE, out.lines = 1:20}
summary(mod)
```
````

Answer (score 1):

The [**knitr** example 052](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples) should give you the basic idea: define the `output` hook, and you can manipulate the text in any way you want.

```
knitr::knit_hooks$set(output = function(x, options) {
  # manipulate x here
})
```

Comment: Thanks Xie for pointing to that example. I was able to get what I intended to achieve. I'm reporting my solution in the first post just in case someone else needs it.

Comment: Please feel free to post it as an answer to your own question, and accept the answer, so that it is no longer an open question.

Comment: Yep, I guess you need to wait for a couple of hours to accept your answer.